# jQuery tabs with hash

Tags: jquery, tabs

Can anybody help me with this fragment of code. I'm try to made basic tabs with hash. But I dont know, whats wrong...

http://jsfiddle.net/QHdvP/1/

Comment: Have you tried [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)?

Answer (score 0):

Why not jquery ui tabs ([jqueryui tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/))?

First error here:

```
showTab($this);
```

Need:

```
showTab($(this));
```

Then I can't understand logic with hash:

```
var tabNumber = tabName.substr(4,1); //string.substr(start,length)
```

There is no elements with name 'tab-1'

Comment: Or you can just pass in the jQuery object $(this) to prevent his other code from breaking `showTab($(this));`

Comment: @wirey Thanks, it's too late ;)